# Import.io Crashes on OS X El Capitan

Tags: crash, import.io, osx-elcapitan

I have updated my OS X to the El Capitan Public Beta (10.11 Beta (15A215h)) and Import.io now does not open anymore. Already tried to erase and reinstalled without success. Does anybody know if there's something I can do to get it to work in this new version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We currently have not tested our app with the beta release of Apple's newest OS.

In the meantime, can you try our beta version of our upcoming app.

The newest app has a bunch of bug fixes and performance improvements. The browser engine has been updated, so less prompts about updating the browser. The app is now 2x faster than the previous update.

Here is to link to install the latest version:
https://gist.github.com/ianAndrewClark/3f4d2842eb6735a92f0f

Thanks,
Meg